# GCP temporal tables feature, similar to SQL Server

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I noticed that SQL Server has a built-in temporal feature but, in PostgreSQL it seems more of an add-on and in GCP Postgres, the add-ins don't seem to be supported at all.

Is there support for temporal tables in GCP Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw these two links Public Issue Tracker Feature Requests for temporal tables in Cloud SQL for Postgres and it seems the Cloud SQL still does not support this. Also no provided ETA for it to be delivered.

1. https://issuetracker.google.com/68986162
2. https://issuetracker.google.com/154639601

You can star the public issue tracker feature requests and add ‘Me too’ in the thread. This will bring more attention to the request as more users request support for it.